# How to add a class for given id

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Here is my code,

```
<svg>
    <path id="a"/>
    <path id="a"/>
    <path id="a"/>
</svg>
```

i added a class in "a"(id) as follow,

```
 $("#a").setAttribute('class', 'highlightPathStyle');
```

but that class was added only first path but i need to apply class in "a"(id).
how to resolve this

Comment: Why do you have non-unique ids?

Comment: $("#a").addClass() method will be used to add class

Comment: Elements should not have same IDs. That is the reason why you can only access the first element with id equals to "a"

Comment: why you are having same ids ???

Comment: IDs should really be unique identifiers. For this sort of styling, you should use class from the beginning.

Comment: @Omri Aharon @ stepashka due to some calculation i have used non-unique ids

Comment: Change the calculation then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having multiple duplicated IDs is against HTML standards. If however this is out of your control (from a plugin or something), then do:

```
$("[id=a]").addClass("highlightPathStyle");
```

Otherwise if you have control over the markup, add a class and select on the class:

```
$(".yourClass").addClass("highlightPathStyle")
```

Answer (score 4):

IDs should be unique, you should rather use same class name:

```
<svg>
  <path class="a"/>
  <path class="a"/>
  <path class="a"/>
</svg>
```

and use class selector:

```
 $(".a").addClass('highlightPathStyle');
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have unique IDs.
You can add a class to an element using `addClass` method:

```
$('svg path#a').addClass('highlightPathStyle');
```

> Adds the specified class(es) to each element in the set of matched elements.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: your class is not adding for the respective selector :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to add a class

```
$("path").removeAttr('id').attr('class','highlightPathStyle');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. ID's should be unique.
2. Classnames should be named qualified.
3. addClass adds classes even if they are already added before. Use this:

So

```
<svg>
    <path class="higlightable"/>
    <path class="higlightable"/>
    <path class="higlightable"/>
</svg>
```

And

```
$('.higlightable').toggleClass('highlightPathStyle',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

they are right. you should use a unique id. It will only read the first id when you try to add a class.

instead, you can do like this

```
<svg>
<path class="a"/>
<path class="a"/>
<path class="a"/>
</svg>
```

if you want to add class at the same time you can do like this

```
$('svg').find('path').addClass('highlightPathStyle');
```

if you want to add class on a specific path when you click it

```
$('.a').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('highlightPathStyle');
});
```